# Why do I get an error when calling a stored procedure from C#?

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# and I have a stored procedure in SQL Server:

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[sp_getUserInfo]
        @TelNo = N'2537743007'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

and try call that with this code:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SERVICE;Initial Catalog=InvokeADSL;Integrated Security=True"))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_getUserInfo", con))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        //cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtFirstName.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@TelNo", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "253774300";

        con.Open();

        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(reader["return_value"].ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

but I get an error:

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: return_value
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.FieldNameLookup.GetOrdinal(String fieldName) 
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetOrdinal(String name)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_Item(String name)
>   at ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(String[] args)

How can I solve that? Thanks.

This is my stored procedure in SQL Server: [link to code](https://codeshare.io/5QZWDW)

Comment: This exception means that you're trying to access a collection item by index, using an invalid index. An index is invalid when it's lower than the collection's lower bound or greater than or equal to the number of elements it contains.

Comment: @KingReload How can handle collection?

Comment: Use index position instead of name. reader[0].ToString()

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20940980/7707749 here's a whole explenation about what could cause this problem ;) try solve it yourself for learning purposes, I'm sure you'll figure it out

Comment: Double check the final `SELECT` in your stored procedure.  Shouldn't it be just `SELECT @return_value`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, from the code you're showing as to how to **call** this stored procedure in T-SQL, it seems that the value is being returned from the stored procedure via a **RETURN** statement - **not** as a result set (`SELECT ....`).

<strike>Therefore, you need to read the **return value** of the stored procedure - not a result set using `ExecuteReader()`:</strike>

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_getUserInfo", con))
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@TelNo", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "253774300";

    con.Open();

    // get the value from the RETURN statement in the stored procedure
    int returnValue = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    Console.WriteLine("Return value: {0}", returnValue); 
}
```

**Update:** after consulting the stored procedure code, the result *is* in fact being returned by a `SELECT` (as a result set) - so you **do need** to use `ExecuteReader` - but that column just doesn't have a **name**, you so cannot access it using :

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    Console.WriteLine(reader["return_value"].ToString());
}
```

but you need to instead use the numerical index:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    Console.WriteLine(reader[0].ToString());
}
```

Comment: just curious ,  "it seems that the value is being returned from the stored procedure via a RETURN statement " how the code gives this hint..  I  dont get that vibe atall.

Comment: when i run that sp in sql server return value =0 and when run with your code return value=-1,what happen?

Comment: @loneshark99: because of : `EXEC @return_value = [dbo].[sp_getUserInfo]` and then `SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value` - it's the valued returned by `RETURN` that he's showing ....

Comment: @chertchertopert: you need to **SHOW US** the stored procedure code! Please add it to your question ....

Comment: please wait my freind

Comment: share my store procedure myt friend

Answer (score 0):

If your stored procedure just returns one value then use `var res = cmd.ExecuteScalar();` instead of `reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();`.
 But if your stored procedure return table then use `SqlDataAdapter` with your current command like this `SqlDataAdapter DA = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);` and then `DA.Fill(dt);`

Comment: get this output Byte[]

Comment: In your code you can cast it to `int` like this `int res = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();`